# ASP.net webforms creating null Page_Validators

Tags: asp.net, forms, validation, webforms

I have a form page, and I'm getting errors when I submit that are caused by null Page_Validators. I looked at the Page_Validators array, and the first two items are null, though the rest are actual validators that I have on my page. Where are these null values coming from? I need to get rid of them as they're breaking my scripts.

Here is the complete page. I'm not sure what's causing this, so I figure it's best to just include everything:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/wimco.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="new_account.aspx.vb" Inherits="new_account" title="Wimco - New Account" %>
<asp:content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main" Runat="Server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jscripts/formvalidation.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        function XmasCheck01(sender, args) 
        { 
        var arr = document.aspnetForm.ctl00$Main$txtArrive01.value;
        var nights = document.aspnetForm.ctl00$Main$ddlNights01.value; 
        var xmas = new Date(2008, 11, 15); // Dec 15th
        var nyears = new Date(2009, 0, 1); // Jan 1st
        var m;
        var d;
        var n = parseInt(nights); 
        var arrive = new Date(); 
        arrive.setTime(Date.parse(arr)); 
        var depart = new Date(arrive.getFullYear(), arrive.getMonth(), arrive.getDate() + n);
        if(arrive<=nyears && arrive>=xmas && n<14) 
            args.IsValid = false; 
            else 
            args.IsValid = true; 
            };

        function XmasCheck02(sender, args) 
        { 
        var arr = document.aspnetForm.ctl00$Main$txtArrive02.value;
        var nights = document.aspnetForm.ctl00$Main$ddlNights02.value; 
        var xmas = new Date(2008, 11, 15); // Dec 15th
        var nyears = new Date(2009, 0, 1); // Jan 1st
        var m;
        var d;
        var n = parseInt(nights); 
        var arrive = new Date(); 
        arrive.setTime(Date.parse(arr)); 
        var depart = new Date(arrive.getFullYear(), arrive.getMonth(), arrive.getDate() + n);
        if(arrive<=nyears && arrive>=xmas && n<14) 
            args.IsValid = false; 
            else 
            args.IsValid = true; 
            } 

    </script> 
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlNewUser" runat="server" Visible="true">


<div id="leftContent">
            <h1>Setting Up Your Vacation Account</h1>
            <p>Fill out the form below to customize your vacation search. Your preferences will be remembered each time you visit Wimco.
</p>            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" align="center" style="position: relative; z-index: 100" id="form-table">
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">* First Name:</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox
                            ID="txtFirstName"
                            TextMode="SingleLine"
                            EnableViewState="True"
                            Columns="20"
                            MaxLength="48"
                            CssClass="iField"
                            Runat="Server"/>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="FNReq"
                            ControlToValidate="txtFirstName"
                            ValidationGroup="NewUser" 
                            Display="None"
                            ErrorMessage="<b>Required Field Missing</b><br />A first name is required." />  
                        <ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender runat="Server" ID="NReqE"
                            TargetControlID="FNReq"
                            HighlightCssClass="validatorCalloutHighlight" />    
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">* Last Name:</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox
                            ID="txtLastName"
                            TextMode="SingleLine"
                            EnableViewState="True"
                            Columns="20"
                            MaxLength="48"
                            CssClass="iField"
                            Runat="Server"/>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="LNReq"
                            ControlToValidate="txtLastName"
                            ValidationGroup="NewUser" 
                            Display="None"
                            ErrorMessage="<b>Required Field Missing</b><br />A last name is required." />
                        <ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender runat="Server" ID="LNReqE"
                            TargetControlID="LNReq"
                            HighlightCssClass="validatorCalloutHighlight" />    
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">* Email Address:</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox
                            ID="txtNewEmail"
                            TextMode="SingleLine"
                            EnableViewState="True"
                            Columns="20"
                            MaxLength="48"
                            CssClass="iField"
                            Runat="Server"/>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="EMReq"
                            ControlToValidate="txtNewEmail"
                           ValidationGroup="NewUser"  
                            Display="None"
                            ErrorMessage="<b>Required Field Missing</b><br />Your entry is not a valid e-mail address." />
                        <ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender runat="Server" ID="EMReqE"
                            TargetControlID="EMReq"
                            HighlightCssClass="validatorCalloutHighlight" />
                        <div class="error-message"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">* Password:</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox
                            ID="txtNewPassword"
                            TextMode="Password"
                            EnableViewState="True"
                            Columns="20"
                            MaxLength="48"
                            CssClass="iField"
                            Runat="Server"/>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
                            ID="PWReq"
                            ControlToValidate="txtNewPassword"
                           ValidationGroup="NewUser"  
                            Display="None"
                            ErrorMessage="<b>Required Field Missing</b><br />A password is required."
                            Runat="Server"/>
                        <ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender runat="Server" ID="PWReqE"
                            TargetControlID="PWReq"
                            HighlightCssClass="validatorCalloutHighlight" />
                        <div class="error-message"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">* Re-type Password:</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox
                            ID="txtPasswordConfirm"
                            TextMode="Password"
                            EnableViewState="True"
                            Columns="20"
                            MaxLength="48"
                            CssClass="iField"
                            Runat="Server"/>
                        <asp:CompareValidator
                            ID="vldPasswordsMatch"
                            ControlToValidate="txtPasswordConfirm"
                            ControlToCompare="txtNewPassword"
                            Display="Dynamic"
                            Text="<br/ >The passwords you entered do not match."
                            Operator="Equal"
                            Type="String"
                            Runat="Server"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">Arrival:</td>
                    <td>
                        <!--<asp:Image runat="Server" ID="Image3" ImageUrl="images/calendar.png" />-->
                        <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender 
                            ID="CalendarExtender1" 
                            runat="server"
                            TargetControlID="txtArrive02"
                            CssClass="wrapCal"
                            PopupButtonID="Image3" />
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtArrive02" CssClass="iField" style="width: 80px; border-color: #FFF" />
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNights02" runat="server" style="width: 95px">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="7 Nights" Value="7" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="8 Nights" Value="8" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="9 Nights" Value="9" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="10 Nights" Value="10" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="11 Nights" Value="11" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="12 Nights" Value="12" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="13 Nights" Value="13" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="14 Nights" Value="14" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="15 Nights" Value="15" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="16 Nights" Value="16" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="17 Nights" Value="17" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="18 Nights" Value="18" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="19 Nights" Value="19" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="20 Nights" Value="20" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="21 Nights" Value="21" />
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvXmas02" 
                            ControlToValidate="txtArrive02" Display="None" runat="server" 
                            ValidationGroup="NewUser"
                            ErrorMessage="For the Holiday season, there is a 14 day minimum stay" 
                            ClientValidationFunction="XmasCheck02" />
                        <ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender  ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender1" 
                            TargetControlID="cvXmas02" runat="server" /> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <asp:Button
                            ID="btnCreateAccount"
                            CssClass="formBut btn btn-load float-left create-account"
                            Text="Create Account"
                            CausesValidation="True"
                             ValidationGroup="NewUser"
                            Runat="Server" />

                        <a class="formBut btn btn-load float-left validation-button">Create Account</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="rightContent" style="z-index:1;">
            <h3>Benefits of a Wimco Vacation Account</h3>
            <ul style="margin: 0; padding-left: 10px">
                <li>See the availability calendar for all 1,500 villas in St Barts, the Caribbean and Europe</li>
                <li>Villa search tool that shows you which villas are available on your preferred dates</li>
                <li>Villa Suitcase feature – store and compare your favorite villas</li>
            </ul>
            <h3>Already have an account?</h3>
            <p><asp:HyperLink ID="hlMembers" NavigateUrl="login.aspx?ref=mem" runat="server">Members log-in here</asp:HyperLink><br />
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" NavigateUrl="login.aspx?ref=email" runat="server">Email a lost password here</asp:HyperLink>
</p>        </div>
        <asp:Label ID="lblPageState" runat="server" />
    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel ID="pnlUserCreated" HorizontalAlign="Left" Visible="False" Runat="Server">
    <!-- User Account Successfully Created -->
    <asp:Label ID="lblRedirect" Runat="Server"/>
    <p>If you're seeing this message for more than a few seconds, your browser may have Javascript disabled. <a href="/villas/villasearch.aspx?pnl=c">To continue click here.</a>
</p></asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel ID="pnlUserExists" HorizontalAlign="Left" Visible="False" Runat="Server">
    <h1>Setting Up Your Vacation Account</h1>
    <!-- User Account Exists with a different password -->
    <h4>Email Address Exists</h4>
    <p>We found an account using this email address already.
</p>    <p><a href="login.aspx">Log in here...</a>
</p></asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel ID="pnlUserNotCreated" Visible="False" Runat="Server">
    <h1>Setting Up Your Vacation Account</h1>
    <!-- User Account Not Created - Unknown error-->
    <h4>Database Error on Login</h4>
    <p>There was an error while attempting to log you in. Use the link below to try again. If you keep getting this error message, the service is experiencing a temporary technical problem. Try back in an hour.
</p>    <p><a href="login.aspx">Log in here...</a>
</p>    <asp:Label ID="lnkAddSuitcase" Visible="False" Runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="lnkRemSuitcase" Visible="False" Runat="server"></asp:Label>
</asp:Panel>
</asp:content>
```

Comment: Is it supposed to say `Page Language="VB"`? This isn't tagged as, nor does it look like VB. Dunno if that is the issue, but it seems fishy.

Comment: My mistake, it is VB, not C#.

Comment: "getting errors"  Care to share the error messages?

Comment: Page_Validators[0] is null. Cannot get value of null object